# How to send Jqxgrid in a form without using hidden textbox?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jqxgrid

My CI view consists of a grid and data is added dynamically to this grid.This is saved to a database when a save button is clicked..
Here is the screenshot of the view.
[IMG]http://i40.tinypic.com/16a7dhl.png[/IMG]

When I submit the form,Grid data is first stored in an array and then array elements are joined together with a seperator in between them into a string.This string is stored in a hidden textbox and is submitted along with the form.After submission,in the controller they are seperated again & stored in the database.I have read that this method is prone to error.

Is there a better way to send array of data in a table to the controller than the above method? I have used Jqxgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jqxGrid's "getrows" to get all records as an Array.

Comment: shouldn't i get the array into a textbox to pass it along the form?Is there anyway i can avoid that?

Comment: I don't think so. "getrows" fill return an array of all loaded rows. Then you can loop through the rows and built a String. From that string, fill the textbox or a hidden textbox. Another option is to export it to JSON,  var data = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'json'); and fill the textbox with that data.

Comment: OK...i used the json.stringify method...Using getrows I looped through grid to get it in an array,converted the array to string using json.stringify(array_name) and stored it in a hidden textbox...and at the controller/server side, used json_decode in php to convert the string back to array...atleast i could avoid joining and splitting back arrays from view to controller that i used earlier...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array for the names of the fields.

```
<input type="hidden" name="field_name[]" value="foo">
<input type="hidden" name="field_name[]" value="bar">
```

---

```
$post = $this->input->post();
extract($post);
foreach($field_name as $k => $v){
    $this->db->insert('tablename', array('fieldname' => $v));
}
```

Comment: In the above case,should i use textbox for every cell of the grid? Is there any option in JQxgrid which will store them in array?